Ensuring Data Consistency Between Two Modules in ASP.NET Core Application
I’m developing an ASP.NET Core application with a modular monolithic architecture. I have two independent modules: one for image upload/download and another for QR code scanning/decryption. The first module handles the upload and download of invoice images, while the second module scans, decrypts, and saves the data from the invoice.
The challenge I’m facing is ensuring that the saved data from the QR code scan has a reference to its corresponding image for a smoother download process. This becomes particularly tricky when the QR code is scanned and decrypted before the image is uploaded.
I’m looking for a systematic way to ensure that each piece of data is correctly associated with its corresponding image, regardless of the order in which the image upload and QR code scan occur. Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
The method in the module handling the scans, decryption and data saving is made to return no content.
 public async Task HandleAsync(CreateScan command, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
 {

         if (command.Data == null)
             throw new InvalidPostRequestException(command.Data);


         //decryption codes...

         // saving decrypted code value codes...


         _logger.LogInformation($"New Data  with ID: {data.Id}created successfully.");
     
 }


The problem is too broad TBH. How images and codes are related? Based on some Id? If yes then why not just create the parent data if it is not present (with some state like "not uploaded")?

"not just create the parent data if it is not present (with some state like "not uploaded")?"
Because at some point, the image will have to be downloaded to make further checks, and the checks would have to correspond with the decrypted QR data.

And how the suggested solution prevents this?
